# Retrieve the first element from Counter in O(n) time

Tags: python

I have such a nums list

```
In [72]: nums                                                                                                                 
Out[72]: [4, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

try to get the unique number from the list

```
n [72]: nums                                                                                                                 
Out[72]: [4, 1, 2, 1, 2]

In [73]: c = Counter(nums)                                                                                                    

In [74]: c                                                                                                                    
Out[74]: Counter({4: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2})
```

I can see the result from the counter, it is `4:1`, but cannot retrieve it in O(1) time

```
In [79]: list(c)[0]                                                                                                           
Out[79]: 4 #O(n) time
```

Is it possible to get 4 in O(1)time

Comment: what does *first element* for `Counter` mean? i mean if you just have a `Counter` object how would you determine which is the *first* element?

Comment: `next(iter(c))`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey ah, just *any* element? then i agree!

Comment: Oh, yes, I got your point @hiroprotagonist

Comment: or... maybe you want the count of the first element in your list - in which case you can do `c[nums[0]]`... but *first*... like @hiro says - is somewhat ambiguous...

Comment: yes, I know the decent solution `[k for k, v in c.items() if v ==1][0]` @JonClements

Comment: @Alice well... that's a solution to something... that'll give you the key of the first element whose count is 1... but that's not quite the same as the question you're asking... you could also write that as `next(k for k, v in c.items() if v == 1)` to avoid building a list and then taking the first element of that list... but again - *first* is ambiguous here... Is what you're asking boiling down to... "how do I get the item of `nums` in the order they appear in that list that is unique"?

Comment: could you please transmit the comment to answer. @JonClements

Comment: @Alice I'm afraid I still don't know what the question is that, that could be an answer to. If you could [edit] your question to clarify exactly what it is you're trying to achieve (maybe it's what I guessed in my comment or maybe it's something else?) then please do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments to the question, you want to get the elements that have a count of 1. But it is still not clear what you want to get exactly, as the term "the first element" is unclear in the context of a `Counter`, which is a `dict` and no defined order internally.

Here are a few options (I used `str` instead of `int` to make it clearer which are the values and which are their counts):

```
>>> import collections
>>> input_str = 'awlkjelqkdjlakd'
>>> c = collections.Counter(input_str)
>>> c
Counter({'l': 3, 'k': 3, 'a': 2, 'j': 2, 'd': 2, 'w': 1, 'e': 1, 'q': 1})
```

Get all elements that have count of 1 (takes `O(k)`, where `k` is the number of different elements):

```
>>> [char for char, count in c.items() if count == 1]
['w', 'e', 'q']
```

Get one (random, not specified) element that has count of 1 (takes `O(k)`, because the list has to be built):

```
>>> [char for char, count in c.items() if count == 1][0]
'w'
```

This can be improved by using a generator, so the full list will not be built; the generator will stop when the first element with count 1 is found, but there is no way to know if that will be first or last or in the middle ...

```
>>> g = (char for char, count in c.items() if count == 1)
>>> g
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fd520e82f68>
>>> next(g)
'w'
>>> next(char for char, count in c.items() if count == 1)
'w'
```

---

Now, if you want to find the count of the first element of your input data (in my example `input_str`), that is done in `O(1)` because it is a `list` item access and then a `dict` lookup:

```
>>> elem = input_str[0]
>>> elem
'a'
>>> c[elem]
2
```

But I cannot give a more concrete answer without more information on what exactly you need.